# WSO2 Message Broker Unable to show the Message content

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have successfully configured the WSO2 Message Broker. I have also integrated with WSO2 ESB. I have sent a message on a queue from my ProxyService. When i try to browse the message content on queue. WSO2 MB gives me following error:
[image]

**Note:** I am using WSO2 MB 2.2.0.

**Problem:**

I have searched on the internet about this problem. And i think this problem is known to the WSO2. But how can i and where can i find the servicepack or some kind of patch to fix this??. And then how to install that patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the **WSO2 Message Broker 3.0.0 Milestone 1** release which has this fixed from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/scratch/MB/3.0.0/M1/wso2mb-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-m1.zip). This link was taken from a [WSO2 dev mailing list](http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2014-October/038403.html).

The JIRA ticket that contains the changes is [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/MB-699). The patch is attached to the ticket, in case you are curious of the changes that were made to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if i do not want to upgrade, then how can I install the patch.? Suppose i downloaded the patch file but how will i install it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @omerkhalid: I don't think you can apply that patch easily. It contains the git commit of three classes which are part of two jar files: **org.wso2.carbon.andes.core_4.2.0.jar** and **org.wso2.carbon.andes.ui_4.2.0.jar** (_MB_ROOT/repository/components/plugins_ directory). If you would checkout your MB version's code, you could potentially do those changes, build with same Java, and inject the three .class files in your MB's jar files. Just copying the milestone's jars in your version is risky as they did other changes in there.